# Computer repair store claims they can’t recover all data from SSD

Tags: ssd, data-recovery

MacBook mid-2014 broke down and I suspect it’s the motherboard. I needed to recover data from the SSD so the repair store does their thing, coming back 2 weeks later claiming they recovered the data, handing me a flash drive with like 1/100 of the data that was actually on there. They said they did what they could and the rest of the data must have been lost when reformatting or something along those lines.

Are they bs’ing me or is this probably what happened? To confirm, I handed my laptop into another repair store across the road, and am awaiting their response now.

Comment: It could be entirely legitimate. It could also be that they accidentally formatted the drive, although you won't be able to prove this. If the second store restores all your files, you could, of course, get a refund from the first store... or at least request one.

Comment: Depends on the quality of their recovery, and whether they did what you could have done on your own.  When it comes to data recovery, try programs like [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) first, and if unsuccessful, create a `dd` raw image of the drive, which provides a backup copy to attempt recovery against.  If the data is important, and you're unable to recover it on your own, send it to a company that specializes in data recovery, as they will have the ability to potentially recover the data by accessing the flash chips directly via the PCB.

Comment: There should be no reformatting going on with any recovery job. There should also be no using the customer disk to attempt a reinstall as the computer should be tested with drive removed and using a live USB. I would not take anything to those people ever again if I were you.

Comment: The important thing to note is that without observing your drive and the steps taken by the servicer we cannot answer your question with authority. It is simply not possible.